# INTEGRITY RTOS latency

Tags: benchmarking, latency, rtos

I survey the RTOS for evaluation. Does anyone have any benchmark about interrupt response latency on INTEGRITY RTOS?  I had found some benchmark on VxWorks, PREEMT_RT Linux, RTAI, Neutrino,...

http://wiki.csie.ncku.edu.tw/embedded/xenomai/rtlws_paper.pdf

https://content.sciendo.com/configurable/contentpage/journals$002fcjece$002f11$002f2$002farticle-p35.xml

Does anyone have similar benchmark report on INTEGRITY RTOS?

Comment: Last I looked (many years ago and I thing for their compiler rather than RTOS) the Greenhills EULA explicitly prohibited a licence holder to publish benchmarks.  It is arguably not a good way of comparing products since there is no standardisation of test method or platform.  Your best solution is to get an evaluation licence and perform your own tests, to see if the product meets your requirements (and exercise caution if you intend to publish them).

Comment: I would expect in general for all true RTOS to perform comparably and for PREEMT_RT Linux to be something else not worthy of  comparison with an RTOS, although it may still meet your application's needs - if it does, then benchmarks for a true RTOS are probably irrelevant, because if Linux meets your real-time deadlines a real RTOS certainly will.